# Eevee viewport exposure (?) different in layout configurations

Tags: interface, eevee-render-engine

Just noticed that I have deeply different lighting in Eevee in different layouts.
This is the UV EDITOR:
[image]

This is the same corner, same room, but in a layout that I created:
[image]

This is yet another layout I created:
[image]

This is the standard LAYOUT:
[image]

And this is the SHADING laout:
[image]

I really don't know what setting could cause this difference of render in Eevee in different layout vieports.

Comment: Maybe you have different viewport shading settings? Check the arrow next to the shading modes (the 4 circle in the header).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The environment *Strength* setting is a per-layout shading setting.
[image]
It is a multiplier for the environment's color values.

A quick look at the data path will show why it is per-layout:
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!